# I cannot start Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I installed jupyter using

```
pip install jupyter
```

now  when i try to run jupyter using

```
python -m notebook
```

and try to run any ipynb file in it, it show a 500: internel server error
command lines show

```
[W 23:01:34.693 NotebookApp] Error loading server extension ipyparallel.nbextension
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1670, in init_server_extensions
    mod = importlib.import_module(modulename)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\ipyparallel\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .client.asyncresult import *
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\ipyparallel\client\asyncresult.py", line 23, in <module>
    from IPython import get_ipython
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\embed.py", line 14, in <module>
    from IPython.core.magic import Magics, magics_class, line_magic
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import oinspect
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\oinspect.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pygments\formatters\__init__.py", line 143, in __getattr__
    _load_formatters(info[0])
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pygments\formatters\__init__.py", line 39, in _load_formatters
    mod = __import__(module_name, None, None, ['__all__'])
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pygments\formatters\html.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pygments.formatter import Formatter
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pygments\formatter.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pygments.styles import get_style_by_name
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygments.styles'
To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
    file:///C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-20672-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
    http://localhost:8888/?token=8ee269226240ce7b5a7c580664ade26546bb7e0691775535
 or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=8ee269226240ce7b5a7c580664ade26546bb7e0691775535
```

I thought using anaconda might help get rid.
but every time i run anaconda navigator it crashes.
I then tried running anaconda through conda prompt
and what i see it also didn't work for Jupyter plus spyder is having the same problem.
i guess something is wrong with ipykernel.